# how to make tabular data from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Hi iam working on attendance report, data in array we have :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:09:02
                    [eventID] => OUT
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:09:12
                    [eventID] => IN
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:11:31
                    [eventID] => OUT
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:11:40
                    [eventID] => IN
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:13:17
                    [eventID] => OUT
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ActatekLog] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [timeentry] => 2011-02-16 00:13:21
                    [eventID] => IN
                    [terminalSN] => 00111DA08C8B
                    [jpegPhoto] => 
                )

        )

)
```

report format is :

```
Date       In Time     Out Time    Work Time
2011-02-16
```

i need help in display in time and out time in one row for same day.

Please help

Comment: I only see entry times. Could you explain a bit more what we see in the array?

Comment: Thanks for reply Prikkeldraad, what i would like to display data in tabular form like:
DATE | IN TIME | OUT TIME | WORKING HOURS

in time and out time of same date in a row

Comment: when I inspect your array I found that all entries are made in the same date and its 2011-02-16 and there are three INs and three Outs. Then how do you expect that you can have a row based on that info? Please post the returned data that you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using your data model never changes and that your data is already sorted the way you'd like it to be sorted. So, for an array like this:

```
$data = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        'ActateLog' => array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'timeentry' => '2011-02-16 00:09:02',
            'eventID' => 'OUT',
            'terminalSN' => '00111DA08C8B',
            'jpegPhoto' => false
        )
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        'ActateLog' => array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'timeentry' => '2011-02-16 00:09:12',
            'eventID' => 'IN',
            'terminalSN' => '00111DA08C8B',
            'jpegPhoto' => false
        )
    )
);
```

I made a function, that returns an array with n/2 rows and has both IN and OUT in the same row.

```
function processMyArray($data)
{
    $output = array();
    $lim = count($data);
    $i = $j = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<$lim; $i+=2, $j++)
    {
        $output[$j] = array
        (
            'date' => substr($data[$i]['ActateLog']['timeentry'], 0, 10),
            'IN' => substr($data[$i]['ActateLog']['timeentry'], 11),
            'OUT' => substr($data[$i+1]['ActateLog']['timeentry'], 11),
            'work_time' => strtotime($data[$i+1]['ActateLog']['timeentry']) - strtotime($data[$i]['ActateLog']['timeentry'])
        );
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks gilden your solution is great however there is one glitch remaining plz help me to solve this. we need to create a attendance report for required days like 2011-05-01 ~ 2011-05-25. we need to pass a array in your function processMyArray() after a condition is match looping through date,

Comment: like this
`
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
 { 
 $diff3 = daysDifference($contents[$i]['ActatekLog']['timeentry'], $date);
  if($diff3 == 0)
  {$sameDay = $contents[$i];
  $result = processMyArray($sameDay);
  print_r($result);  }   
 }  
`  
function require id and we are passing array with key [ActatekLog] plz help

Answer (score 1):

I would start by formatting the output array a little bit first.

```
$arr = array();
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    $arr[ $row[ 'terminalSN' ] ][ $row[ 'eventID' ] ] = $row;
}
```

Then output should be a little easier:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Work Time</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $value[ 'IN' ][ 'timeentry' ] ) ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime( $value[ 'IN' ][ 'timeentry' ] ) ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime( $value[ 'OUT' ][ 'timeentry' ] ) ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "Calculate based on out minus in. Pretty simple at this point." ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go that'll do it though you dont have two values in your array that you state you want in your table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Work Time</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($thisArr as $arr) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $arr['ActatekLog']['timeentry']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "no time out in the array??"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "you need to calculate this I assume"; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Prikkeldraad, problem with this code is it will not display in time and out time in a row rather in time in one row and out time in next row. Really appreciate you help but we need to polish it, i tried to extract data in a list but no use

Comment: @Tanvier I'm not Prikkeldraad and using your array the code I posted would print out the time in and time out in the same row for every array you have nested.... so I don't understand what you are saying